# MapStruct not autowiring with Kotlin and Spring Boot, built using Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, dependency-injection, mapstruct

I have the following parts in my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
...
    compile("org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.0.Final")
    kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Final")
```

And am also using JUnit 5.

My mapper looks like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface ModelMapper {
    fun convertToDto(forms: Model): DTO

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    fun convertToModel(dto: DTO): Model
}
```

And I'm trying to autowire it similar to such:

```
@Service
@Transactional
class MyService @Autowired constructor(
    private val repository: MyRepository,
    private val mapper: ModelMapper
) {
...
}
```

But when I try to run a test/do a build, I get an error:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '....ModelMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Does anyone know why Spring Boot isn't working with this kind of setup?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458089/mapstruct-implementation-is-not-working-in-spring-boot-web-application

Comment: I've already seen that. The "solution" is to use an interface, which is exactly what I've done. The "top" answer was basically the person hand-writing the mappings. That isn't utilizing MapStruct at all. I do want to emphasize that I'm using Kotlin, and not Java - and although they use the same JVM, Kotlin seems to require workarounds to get things to work.

Comment: The exception you're getting basically says: I don't know which class I should autowire, please create one with type xyz. Although it doesn't make much sense, you could annotate the mapper with @component, which usually solves this problem.

Comment: And regarding the other post: I was referring to the answer by Minnow

Comment: I understand that. And I have tried Minnow's solution (or at least a few gradle variants), and none of it worked.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: No, I did not. I did find more information that may have helped, such as using a mapstruct kotlin library that utilized builders instead. In the end it just didn't seem worth the time and I just hard coded a toModel/toDto method.

Comment: I have the same issue. Problem is the Impl class with implementation for mapper interface is not generated. Therefore spring has no candidate for autowiring

Answer (score 2):

Try passing Spring's annotation processor to kapt in `build.gradle`:

```
kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}")
```

or try keeping javac annotation processors:

```
kapt {
    keepJavacAnnotationProcessors = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this helped me, add this in your build.gradle.kts:

```
    implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct")
    kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor")

    compileOnly(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    kapt(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-configuration-processor")
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is the [solution](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/main/mapstruct-kotlin).

Just the pom.xml has to contains some more info:

```
<executions>
 <execution>
     <id>compile</id>
     <phase>process-sources</phase>
     <goals>
         <goal>compile</goal>
     </goals>
 </execution>
 <execution>
     <id>test-compile</id>
     <phase>test-compile</phase>
     <goals>
         <goal>test-compile</goal>
     </goals>
 </execution>
 <execution>
     <id>kapt</id>
     <goals>
         <goal>kapt</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
         <sourceDirs>
             <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
             <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
         </sourceDirs>
         <annotationProcessorPaths>
             <annotationProcessorPath>
                 <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                 <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                 <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
             </annotationProcessorPath>
         </annotationProcessorPaths>
     </configuration>
 </execution>
```

And then it works

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `@Transactional class{}` then you must have all of its methods open `open fun(){}` to enable `bean Autowiring`,,

> `kotlin spring boot plugin` changes the default behavior of kotlin which opens all classes and methods by defauls

Just add kotlin spring boot plugin in your project's build.gradle

groovy:

```
plugins {
    ....
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.8.22'
}
```

kotlin

```
plugins {
    ....
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add

> kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.3.1.Final")

I'm using mapstruct in springboot using kotlin and gradle.
And everything works fine with autowiring, that's all what i have:

> ```
> apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
>
> compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final"
>
> kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final")
> kapt("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.3.1.Final")
> ```

And configuration for the interface:

> @Mapper(componentModel = "spring", injectionStrategy =
>   InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR)